# AdWords query string breaking links

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, google-ads-api

I have a website that needs .htaccess url rewriting to work. A recently set AdWords announce adds `?gclid=` to the end of the url resulting a 404 error page.
Does anyone how to solve this problem, mantaining both url rewriting and AdWords tracking?

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pensieriecolori.it [NC]
RewriteRule %(.*)$ http://www.pensieriecolori.it/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.php

RewriteRule ^risultati-ricerca  /ricerca.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^risultati-ricerca/ /ricerca.php?idpagina=$1[L]


RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)    /sezione.php?idpagina=$1[L]

RewriteRule ^chi-siamo/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^cosa-facciamo/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^valori/([^/]+) /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)   /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]

RewriteRule ^chi-siamo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^cosa-facciamo/([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio/([^/]+)/([^/]+)  /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^valori/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)   /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]

ErrorDocument 404 /pagina.php?idpagina=$1[L]
Redirect 301 http://pensieriecolori.it http://www.pensieriecolori.it
Redirect 301 http://37.9.226.66 http://www.pensieriecolori.it
```

## Example of broken url

http://www.pensieriecolori.it/cosa-facciamo/agenzia-web-socialmediamarketing?gclid=CMmxhbmn5ckCFSoUwwodoJEDew

This link works normally when you delete `?gclid=...`

Comment: Hi, this isn't going to be clear enough without the exact rewriting instructions you are using on your site, can you edit them in?

Comment: Here you are! Sorry, I didn't think this could have been useful.

Comment: Can you show an example of an URL breaking when Google adds its thing?

Comment: Added! Thank for your support

Comment: The problem can be in your `pagina.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was inside the AdWords declaration of the url: it was enough adding a slash `/` at the end of the url and the page starts to work correctly also with `gclid` parameter set up.